# Spring JPA findAll returns empty after changing spring.datasource.url, even though native query with SELECT * returns data

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have configured my entity, repository, etc and tested against my local DB.  It works as expected,

However, after changing my data source to the production DB in Amazon RDS (it's a MySQL DB), my JPA findAll returns an empty array and findById doesn't find IDs even when they are definitely in the DB.

I tested using a native query that does a SELECT *, and it returns the expected results.

SO THE QUESTION IS:  What could be causing an issue with the JPA syntax like findAll when using this new data source?

```
package com.example.scoopbe.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Category setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Category setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.scoopbe.repository;

import com.example.scoopbe.model.Category;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, String> {

}
```

```
server.port=5000

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

Again, simply changing DB_URL, DB_USER, and DB_PASSWORD causes this issue.  Reverting these values solves the issue.

Comment: When you point the properties at the Amazon db, are there any errors when you start the Spring app?

Comment: @TylerLiu - Spring starts w/out issue.  I'm connected to the DB and can query it so long as I use native query.  findAll and findById do not return results

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that even though the table and entity are named "CATEGORY", JPA uses a lowercase table name, and since it doesn't already exists, it creates a new one called "category".

This new table is empty, so that's why my queries returned empty.  The native query was hitting the correct table "CATEGORY"

Comment: Hello, please bear in mind these few tips:
On Answers: 
- Try to justify your answer using documentation, especially like your case, this can help others in the future.
- Post the code and/or steps in the terminal that resolved the problem.
- Take some time trying and studying before posting questions and answers, if you were able to answer your own question then probably you should have not posted it (I have done this myself many times).
Best regards.